# Splitting my code into multiple files in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I wish to split my code into multiple files in Python 3.

I have the following files:

```
/hello
    __init__.py
    first.py
    second.py
```

Where the contents of the above files are:

**`first.py`**

```
from hello.second import say_hello

say_hello()
```

**`second.py`**

```
def say_hello():
    print("Hello World!")
```

But when I run:

```
python3 first.py
```

while in the `hello` directory I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hello.second import say_hello
ImportError: No module named 'hello'
```

Comment: Have you actually *installed* your package? Added it to the path? Considered a relative import (`from .second import say_hello`) instead?

Comment: I didn't thought you need to. I simply want to split my code into multiple files like you can in almost any language like Java or PHP.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you stop guessing and read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out

```
from hello.second import say_hello
```

for

```
from second import say_hello
```

Your default Python path will include your current directory, so importing straight from `second` will work. You don't even need the `__init__.py` file for this. You *do*, however, need the `__init__.py` file if you wish to import from outside of the package:

```
$ python3
>>> from hello.second import say_hello
>>> # Works ok!
```

Comment: `__init__.py` is no longer needed in Python 3. See [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Comment: Your suggestion causes problems with `import hello.first` when outside the package directory.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run python3 in the hello directory.

You should run it outside the hello directory and run

```
python3
>>> import hello.first
```

By the way, `__init__.py` is no longer needed in Python 3. See [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: this gives me the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello/first.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hello.second import say_hello
ImportError: No module named 'hello'`

Comment: @YahyaUddin: You must have done something wrong as this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are not meant to be imported from the current directory.

It is possible to make it work using `if/else` tests or `try/except` handlers, but it's more work than it is worth.

Just `cd ..` so you aren't in the package's directory and it will work fine.